# what does $ do in Expression Language

Tags: java, jsp, el

what does $ do in Expression Language of Jsp?I want to know the significance of this symbol and its working.please somebody help me in this regard.

FYI i know it is used for printing some value directly instead of going through expression i.e <%= %>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access (the getter methods of) beans with the delimiter $ or # in Expression language.

The language is based on java and case sensitive.